# main methods while setting startup projects

Tags: c#, project, startup, program-entry-point, solution

I'm trying to set two startup projects in my solution, and I have three projects.
So I tried to exclude the Main method in my third project that I do not set as a startup project, and somewhy when I run the solution, it tells me that I don't have a main method. But I don't need a main method, so why? I have two main methods in my startup projects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a project of a certain type expects certain things, otherwise as a project it is invalid. If you configure the solution to not start that project that is all you need to do.

To set startup projects, in the solution explorer right click the solution node, and then 'Set startup projects', then select 'Multiple Startup Projects' and choose which ones you want.

If you have no need for a Main method in a project, but the project requires a Main method, then you probably have chosen the wrong project type. Typically project templates with the name Library in them are the ones that do not have a Main method, such as Class Library or WPF Custom Control Library.

Comment: I just updated my answer to include how to do that. Hope that helps.

Comment: But that's what I did anyways, the problem is it's still asking for Main method in the project that I didn't set up as a startup project.

Comment: Yes, add the method back. Even if it is not called the project needs it. If you want a project that does not execute I suggest using a class library - this project type does not require a main method.